# Create Array in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, sortablejs

I am trying to create an Array using the following method, but so far I only managed to get the data one by one. What I actually wish to accomplish is to store an array with all the data so I can store it in a database using PHP.

So far, my problem is that I can't seem to manage to create a simple array with JS, when I tried using "push" it would return empty arrays.

Is anyone able to help me?

```js
Sortable.create(simpleList, {
  onUpdate: function( /**Event*/ evt) {
    saveUnitsPositions();
  },
});

function saveUnitsPositions() {
  const GETPOSITION = document.querySelectorAll("#simpleList li");
  var positions = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < GETPOSITION.length; i++) {
    positions = GETPOSITION[i].getAttribute('data-value');
    console.log(positions);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="http://SortableJS.github.io/Sortable/Sortable.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />


<ul id="simpleList" class="list-group">
  <li class="list-group-item course-unit" data-value="26321">
    Etude #1
  </li>
  <li class="list-group-item course-unit" data-value="26322">
    Etude #2
  </li>
  <li class="list-group-item course-unit disabled" data-value="Backing Tracks">
    Backing Tracks
  </li>
  <li class="list-group-item course-unit" data-value="26326">
    Backing track Fusion (118 bpm)
  </li>
  <li class="list-group-item course-unit" data-value="26327">
    Backing track Samba (90 bpm)
  </li>
  <li class="list-group-item course-unit disabled" data-value="Apostilas">
    Apostilas
  </li>
  <li class="list-group-item course-unit" data-value="26615" style="transform: translateZ(0px);">
    Etudes
  </li>
  <li class="list-group-item course-unit" data-value="26332">
    Tríades Mutantes – Apostila Completa
  </li>

</ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you try without the `Sortable` it works with the push method. Maybe the problem is with the `Sortable`. And it's correct to use the `push` method and it should work.

EDIT: I tried again, and it works with the Sortable, when you update some position, it fill the array.

```js
Sortable.create(simpleList, {
  onUpdate: function( /**Event*/ evt) {
    saveUnitsPositions();
  },
});

function saveUnitsPositions() {
  const GETPOSITION = document.querySelectorAll("#simpleList li");
  var positions = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < GETPOSITION.length; i++) {
    positions.push(GETPOSITION[i].getAttribute('data-value')); // use push here
    console.log(positions);
  }
}
```

```html
<DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://SortableJS.github.io/Sortable/Sortable.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body>
<ul id="simpleList" class="list-group">
  <li class="list-group-item course-unit" data-value="26321">
    Etude #1
  </li>
  <li class="list-group-item course-unit" data-value="26322">
    Etude #2
  </li>
  <li class="list-group-item course-unit disabled" data-value="Backing Tracks">
    Backing Tracks
  </li>
  <li class="list-group-item course-unit" data-value="26326">
    Backing track Fusion (118 bpm)
  </li>
  <li class="list-group-item course-unit" data-value="26327">
    Backing track Samba (90 bpm)
  </li>
  <li class="list-group-item course-unit disabled" data-value="Apostilas">
    Apostilas
  </li>
  <li class="list-group-item course-unit" data-value="26615" style="transform: translateZ(0px);">
    Etudes
  </li>
  <li class="list-group-item course-unit" data-value="26332">
    Tríades Mutantes – Apostila Completa
  </li>

</ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

`push` changes the array "in place" and returns the length of the updated array.
So `[1,2,3].push(4,5)` will return five - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push
So if you do `var result = [1,2,3].push(4,5)`, result will be 5 and not the array.

This is how to use push:

```
function saveUnitsPositions() {
  const GETPOSITION = document.querySelectorAll("#simpleList li");
  const positions = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < GETPOSITION.length; i++) {
    positions.push(GETPOSITION[i].getAttribute('data-value'));
  }
  console.log(positions);
}
```

Alternatively, you could use the `concat` method - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat - which doesn't modify the original array, but instead returns a new array with the concatenated result:

```
function saveUnitsPositions() {
  const GETPOSITION = document.querySelectorAll("#simpleList li");
  var positions = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < GETPOSITION.length; i++) {
    positions = positions.concat( GETPOSITION[i].getAttribute('data-value') );
  }
  console.log(positions);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, I ended up trying the first answer and it worked. But I appreciate your help!